# how to switch from one view to another without destroying the old one in non mobile app

Tags: sapui5

I am wondering how can i go for example from shell to form page and then go back to shell to its current status when i am done with the form. for example i have things inspector open in shell and i want to go back to the same thing inspector when i leave form page. without using mobile library.
at the moment i do the following but i am wondering if there is a better way?

```
                var mainShellView = sap.ui.getCore().byId("Shell1");
                var formView = sap.ui.jsview("formView", "form");
                oTI.exit();
                mainShellView.destroy();
                formView.placeAt("content");
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not use the Shell itself to navigate between views / forms? That's the main purpose of the Shell control anyway ;-)

Just set

```
mainShellView.setContent(<your_view_reference>);
```

accordingly to switch between different views inside your shell

Comment: One issue I have if I use setContent is tool pop ups are still stay there and I need to manually destroy them. But I think its a design issue that my application have anyway.